# Better quality at google Cloud Text to Speech

Tags: google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech, make.com

I am using Google Cloud Text to Speech modules in Integromat for my Adalo app. I want to have better audio quality, so I've already switched to WaveNet and increased the Sample Rate to 48000 Hertz, but it still has pretty bad quality. What can I do? Every idea is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify the `effectsProfileId`, as per the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/audio-profiles

```js
const effectsProfileId = ['telephony-class-application'];

const request = {
  input: {text: text},
  voice: {languageCode: languageCode, ssmlGender: ssmlGender},
  audioConfig: {audioEncoding: 'MP3', effectsProfileId: effectsProfileId},
};
```

The quality of the speech waxes and wanes according to what sort of device you say you're playing the resulting audio through.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your data to the recommended encoding mentioned by Google . Us e the same format as mentioned in Google docs like Flac format. That will give a proper accuracy.
Use stereo recording ,separate Chanel's for speakers .